# How to programmatically generate stylus like input with pressure information?

Tags: c#, android, .net

I want to create small weekend project where I could use galaxy note phone as tablet/stylus input for PC (because this particular phone supports stylus hover and some low but still pressure sensitivity).
And I'm wondering how to approach sending pressure information. I could just generate mouse cursor movement/click events, but that means I lose pressure data.

Maybe someone could guide me in wright direction for generating stylus like input with pressure information?

Comment: I’ve added the [android] tag since that seems relevant (since you need to read pressure information in the first place). If it isn’t, feel free to remove it.